# Android chrisbanes Action bar pull to refresh not working in nested layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

Action bar pull to refresh not working in the following case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_btns_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/allstores_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="all" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stores_nearme_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="near me" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stores_ifallow_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dfdf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/store_listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_btns_layout"
            android:background="#ddd"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using this library with sherlock library, and i am also using actionbarsherlock

lib. I dont know how to use AbsPullToRefreshAttacher which is using to add custom views to

pull to refresh, can any one please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is 'this library' ?

Comment: its Chrisbanes Actionbar-PulltoRefresh lib:https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Comment: Why not trying https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh .

Answer (score 0):

> **Supported Views** 
>   ActionBar-PullToRefresh has in-built support for:
>
> AbsListView derivatives (ListView & GridView)
>   ScrollView 
>   WebView

so in your case just sorround your RelativeLayout and ListView with a ScrollView.

if you dont like this solution u have to read the documentation =/